# 'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, next.js, port, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn dev`
It shows this following error on command prompt:

```
yarn run v1.22.11
$ PORT=3005 next dev
'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

My `package.json` is like:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "PORT=3005 next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

How to fix this error?

Note: I am using Windows OS.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: on.... which OS? because yeah, that's pretty true. For cross-platform environment setting, you probably want to prefix that using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Comment: Yes its on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on Windows OS:

And fixed this using `"dev": "next dev -p 3005"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me.  Has something changed?

Comment: nope i just use this and works fine for me, i think you have any other issues please check it on terminal or you can see other answer on my posts

Comment: It worked for me on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Change your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Then create a `.env` file in your project directory, and set this:

'.env' file

```
PORT=3005
```

then run your project :)

Answer (score 0):

in package.json write "start": "react-scripts start", instead of this  "start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts start",